# Android App Stops working when I click certain Button

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having issue with my app, my app loads however when I click on "options" button it stops working and quits the app.

Can someone help me?

first code is from options.java class and second code is from mainactivity

package com.example.sportsquizzone;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

/**
* Created by Usman on 22/02/2016.
*/
public class options extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);
}
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent b = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    b.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(b);

}

public void btnAbout(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder About = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    About.setMessage("* Developed by Usman Saddique \n* Developed on      \n* This game runs on Android version 4.2 and above")
            .setPositiveButton("Close", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setTitle("About")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.question_mark)
            .create();
    About.show();
}
}
```

package com.example.sportsquizzone;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnPlay)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, level.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnOptions)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, option.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void Instructions(View view) {
final AlertDialog.Builder Instructions = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
Instructions.setMessage("The SQZ is designed to test your knowledge  across variety of sports, to play: \n1. Click Play \n2. Select Dificulty   \n3. when quiz begins, four answers will be provided select the correct one.     ")
     .setPositiveButton("Got It", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setTitle("Instructions")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.question_mark)
            .create();
    Instructions.show();

}

public void btnQuit(View view) {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.warning)
    .setTitle("Closing Application")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Quit?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();
    }

})
.setNegativeButton("No", null)
.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace from logcat when asking for help for a crash.

Comment: Have you declared your options class on manifest?

Comment: Thanks you "statosdotcom" I completely forgot to add it to manifest, after doing this it is working. Thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see the your logcat error but I think you have created the "option" class and its layout separately. So if it is what you have done , probably you have forgotten to declare the activity on manifest:
include it on your manifest: